# Have I split up these Constructs incorrectly?

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I'm fairly new to CDK and I've tried migrating something from vanilla JavaScript to TypeScript, in doing so trying to make it a little more modular. This is the current structure that I've got:

CdkStack.ts

```
constructor(scope: cdk.Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    // API Gateway
    const api = new API(scope, "API");
}
```

Api.ts

```
export class API extends Construct {
    public restApi: RestApi;

    constructor(scope: Construct, id: string) {
        super(scope, id);

        const restApi = new RestApi(this, "website-api", {
            restApiName: "website-api",
            description: "This service provides API calls for the website.",
        });

        const getListLambda = new GetListLambda(
            scope,
            "GetListLambda"
        );

        const listApi = restApi.root.addResource("list");
        listApi.addMethod("GET", getListLambda.integration); // GET /
    }
}
```

GetListLambda.ts

```
export class GetListLambda extends Construct {
    public lambdaFunction: Function;
    public integration: LambdaIntegration;

    constructor(scope: Construct, id: string) {
        super(scope, id);

        this.lambdaFunction = new Function(this, "GetListLambda", {
            runtime: Runtime.NODEJS_12_X,
            code: new AssetCode("lambdas/getList", {
                exclude: ["*.local.js", "*.test.js"],
            }),
            handler: "index.handler",
            environment,
        });

        this.integration = new LambdaIntegration(this.lambdaFunction, {
            proxy: true,
        });
    }
}
```

I used to have basically the same code, but all in a single file. With this current structure I get the following output when I try to do a deploy:

> No stack could be identified for the construct at path API/website-api
>
> /src/api/node_modules/@aws-cdk/aws-apigateway/lib/restapi.ts:540
>       if (this.methods.length === 0) {
>                        ^ TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
>       at RestApi.validate (/src/api/node_modules/@aws-cdk/aws-apigateway/lib/restapi.ts:540:22)
>       at RestApi.onValidate (/src/api/node_modules/@aws-cdk/core/lib/construct-compat.ts:97:17)
>       at Node.validate (/src/api/node_modules/constructs/lib/construct.ts:445:54)
>       at Node.validate (/src/api/node_modules/constructs/lib/construct.ts:442:45)
>       at Node.validate (/src/api/node_modules/constructs/lib/construct.ts:442:45)
>       at Node.synthesize (/src/api/node_modules/constructs/lib/construct.ts:391:27)
>       at Function.synth (/src/api/node_modules/@aws-cdk/core/lib/construct-compat.ts:231:22)
>       at App.synth (/src/api/node_modules/@aws-cdk/core/lib/app.ts:142:36)
>       at process. (/src/api/node_modules/@aws-cdk/core/lib/app.ts:121:45)
>       at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:422:26)

The error reads as though there aren't any methods, however I've clearly added a method to the API.

Comment: Should you be using `const api = new API(this, "API");` instead, to pass down the reference to the stack for the underlying modules?

Comment: @dmahapatro that might well be the problem! Thanks. You might want to add an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using

```
const api = new API(this, "API");
```

instead of

```
const api = new API(scope, "API");
```

will pass down the stack reference to the underlying modules.